# Links fitting 100% of the space

Tags: html, css

Alright so I am creating a link bar, I am wanting to have five links on it.

```
<a href="link1">Link1</a>
<a href="link2">Link2</a>
<a href="link3">Link3</a>
<a href="link4">Link4</a>
<a href="link5">Link5</a>
```

I also don't want the links to have the same width so if one takes up 100px I want them all to be 100px. I am wanting them to also take up 100% of the space.

```
a{
     /* What would be the code */
}
```

Comment: You will need Javascript for this.

Comment: @Paulie_D why would JS be needed?

Comment: false, you don't need javascript.

Comment: display: block; and proper padding.

Comment: and make up your mind OP cuz "don't want the links to have the same width" and "one takes up 100px...all to be 100px" is a complete  contradiction of itself

Comment: Really....how would CSS know the width of the widest link AND then apply it to the rest of the links?

Comment: @Paulie_D using percentages

Comment: Oops didn't mean to  put "don't want"

Comment: @leblma Such a modest guy!

Comment: thanks @dfsq your comment is appreciated, but useless, cauz everybody appreciates me and my modesty, so it has no value for me

Comment: Not super clear what OP wants, but seems to me that something like this http://jsfiddle.net/6ZW6W/

Answer (score 0):

If there's five links

```
a{
    width:20%;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**This should help**

## [Visual demonstration :)](http://jsfiddle.net/Btj5B/)

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
a {
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display: table;` to create a generalized solution for an arbitrary number of links (if you don't care for IE6-7):

HTML:

```
<div class="linkWrapper">
    <a href="link1">Link1</a>
    <a href="link2">Link2</a>
    <a href="link3">Link3</a>
    <a href="link4">Link4</a>
    <a href="link5">Link5</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.linkWrapper {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
.linkWrapper a {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

`table-layout: fixed;` Causes the width of each to link to only depend of the width of the linkWrapper. This way, all of the links will always be the same width and their text will wrap if it exceeds this width.